# Spring Data Save or Update by specific key

Tags: database, spring, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data to persist data in a Oracle DB so, I have my entity called `MessageEntity` and it has the following fields:

```
{
"id":"id", // primary key
"protocol":"protocol",
"message":"message"
}
```

So, I want to save or update the entity by the field `procotol`, using the `Repository<MessageEntity, Long>`. I know I can use method `MessageEntity save(MessageEntity entity)` but it uses primary key. Can i do that?

Comment: so you want to update an element with a specific protocol right? is the protocol unique?

Comment: Yes, i want to update if there is a element with the specific procotol. If doesn't exist, create it. It's unique the procotol.